# 'float' object is not subscriptable error when accesing object

Tags: pandas, lambda, apply

I have results of fotball matches in format 2:1 (2:0,0:1) which is dtype object. I need to create new column called home_goals and insert first number of the result.

```
df['HOME_GOALS'] = df["RESULT"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

This code return me an error 'float' object is not subscriptable.

Thanks for advice

Comment: Do you need `df['HOME_GOALS'] = df["RESULT"].str[0]` ?

Comment: In column are tuples? Or strings?

Comment: In column is string (dtype = object). And I need fill the first number of this string to the new column df['HOME_GOALS']

Comment: What is `print (type(df["RESULT"].iat[0]))` ?

Comment: class "str"..Thanks for your help, df['HOME_GOALS'] = df["RESULT"].str[0] this works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are strings you can seelct first digit by indexing:

```
df['HOME_GOALS'] = df["RESULT"].str[0]
```

But if need first number possible with multiple digits like `10:5` need different solution:

```
df['HOME_GOALS'] = df["RESULT"].str.split(':').str[0]
```

Or:

```
df['HOME_GOALS'] = df["RESULT"].str.extract('(\d+)')
```